# Getting output of another script while preserving line-breaks

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

I'm running a C program from a bash script and would like to capture the last line of output and the exit code. 
This is what I did:

```
echo  output=$(echo $op | ./compute)
echo  $output
echo "$output"
```

Both outputs don't preserve line breaks.
I thought of using `tail -1` but that changes the exit code which is important to me.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `$?` variable, which stores the return value of the last command run.

Also, for to preserve line breaks, you need to use the quotes (`""`) when you're reading the output, not after:

```
# Save your C program's whole output (with newlines)
output="$(echo $op | ./compute)"
# Print exit code
echo $?
# Print the last line of your program's output
echo $(echo "$output" | tail -1)
```